# Maven Dependency Convergence Error on Direct Dependency

Tags: maven, pom.xml

i've encountered a weird dependency convergency error while `maven-enforcer-plugin` is complaining about dependency convergency error on my direct dependency.

For example:

```
A -- B:1.0
|
-- C:1.0
   |
   -- B:1.1
```

A is my project and i specify B:1.0 as A's direct dependency in A's pom file. However, A also depends on C:1.0, which has a transitive dependency on B:1.1. Now maven is complaining about convergency error on `B:1.0` and `B:1.1`.

In my understanding, once i specified a direct dependency in the master pom, we will stick to the version all the way for our project?

In this example, it should be B:1.0 that will be used by the project.

Am i understanding it incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: How can B:1.0 depends on a newer version of itself?

Comment: @Jens My Mistake, corrected my graph

Comment: Use exclude to exclude the newer dependency. But you can run in very specific problems, while using incompatible versions

Answer (score 0):

To resolve convergence Errors, put the chosen dependency version into `<dependencyManagement>`.

A direct dependency will not resolve this kind of error.